# zeroclipboard pasting actual swf / js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, zeroclipboard

Has anyone ran into ZeroClipboard pasting the actual file extension and not the desired content?

My code is

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascripts/ZeroClipboard.js"></script>


<script language="JavaScript">
$(document).ready(function() {

 var clip = new ZeroClipboard($("#copy_button"), {
  moviePath: "javascripts/ZeroClipboard.swf"
  });     
  });
 </script>


 </head>

  <body>


   <button id='#copy_button' data-clipboard-target='to_copy'><b>Copy To Clipboard</b></button>  

    <p id='to_copy'>This should be copied text</p>
```

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out.